# Choose pool on job template based on variable declared at parent stage using yaml azure devops pipeline (AZDO)

Tags: if-statement, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template

My pipeline has a stage similar to this one

```
stages:
- stage: DeployToEnv
  displayName: Deploy App
  variables:
    - group: Settings
    - name: DOL.Environment
      value: dev
  jobs:
  - template: ${{ parameters.postDeployJobTemplate }}
```

In my post-deploy template, I'd like to use a pool based on the environment, which is defined in the stage variables with variable `DOL.Environment`

I have tried:

1 - empty value

```
jobs:
- job: postDeployScriptStepsJob
  displayName: Post Deploy Script Steps
  pool:
    ${{ if eq(variables['DOL.Environment'], 'noprod') }}:
      name: ${{parameters.poolNoProd}}
    ${{ if eq(variables['DOL.Environment'], 'prod') }}:
      name: ${{parameters.poolProd}}
```

2 - syntax error

```
jobs:
- job: postDeployScriptStepsJob
  displayName: Post Deploy Script Steps
  pool:
    - ${{ if eq('$(DOL.Environment)', 'noprod') }}:
        name: ${{parameters.poolNoProd}}
    - ${{ if eq('$(DOL.Environment)', 'prod') }}:
      name: ${{parameters.poolProd}}
```

3 - variables not expected here

```
parameters:
- name: env
  displayName: Environment
  type: string
  
variables:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.env, 'noprod') }}: 
  - name: poolName
    value: np
- ${{ if eq(parameters.env, 'prod') }}: 
  - name: poolName
    value: pr

jobs:
- job: postDeployScriptStepsJob
  displayName: Post Deploy Script Steps
  pool:
    name: $(poolName)
```

Unfortunately, since the stage is used by other teams too as part of another template, I cannot pass the pool name as a parameter however, I could pass the environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the variables like below.

For example, you have 2 YAML files, one is YAML A and another is YAML B.

YAML A:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
stages:
- stage: DeployToEnv
  displayName: Deploy App
  variables:
    - name: test
      value: noprod
    - name: system.debug
      value: true
  jobs:
  - template: azure-pipelines-1.yml
    parameters:
      test: ${{ variables.test }}
```

and YAML B:

```
parameters:
  - name: test
    type: string
jobs:
  pool:
    ${{ if eq(parameters.test, 'noprod') }}:
      name: VMAS2
    ${{ elseif eq(parameters.test, 'prod') }}:
      name: VMAS
  steps:
    - script: echo ${{ parameters.test }}
```

On my side it works fine:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with `condition` passing parameters, but ideally, I want to do the `if` check on the `DOL.Environment` which is set on the `stage` that calls the `job` template.